# Parse Cloud Code afterSave called with empy request

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have this simple trigger function:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Iap", function(request) {
    console.log("request: ", request);
});
```

and it get's called with an empy `request`.

I get this in the logs:

```
I2015-02-26T14:53:40.817Z]v180 after_save triggered for ABTesting as master:
    Input: {"object":{"createdAt":"2015-02-26T14:53:40.782Z",...,"objectId":"tredfg5reresd","updatedAt":"2015-02-26T14:53:40.782Z"}}
    Result: Success
I2015-02-26T14:53:40.830Z]request:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the native Parse console automatically concatenates values. Try the following instead: `console.log("request: " + request);`

Comment: It worked! Now the next question would be, why doesn't it support that?! Isn't Parse running on node.js?